# Proguard - Fragments and view models are not obfuscated

Tags: android, android-fragments, proguard

I am using nav graph and compose. The default proguard rules do not rename fragments. I assume that is by design because the fragment classes are referenced in the nav graph xml by their class name. But I want to have the fragments obfuscated.

The best result I have achieved so far is with the following configuration and it keeps fragments and **SOME** viewmodels in their original package in their original names

What would be the proper way to handle this scenario?

```
-repackageclasses

-whyareyoukeeping class androidx.fragment.app.Fragment { *; }

-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes Exceptions, InnerClasses, Signature, Deprecated, SourceFile, LineNumberTable, *Annotation*, EnclosingMethod

-optimizationpasses 10
-mergeinterfacesaggressively
-dontpreverify
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic

-repackageclasses 'com.o'
-allowaccessmodification
-useuniqueclassmembernames
-keeppackagenames doNotKeepAThing

-overloadaggressively
-flattenpackagehierarchy 'com.touch.simulator'
 
 

-dontwarn kotlinx.coroutines.debug.*

-keep class kotlin.** { *; }
-keep class kotlinx.** { *; }
-keep class kotlinx.coroutines.** { *; }
-keep class org.jetbrains.skia.** { *; }
-keep class org.jetbrains.skiko.** { *; }

-assumenosideeffects public class androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerKt {
    void sourceInformation(androidx.compose.runtime.Composer,java.lang.String);
    void sourceInformationMarkerStart(androidx.compose.runtime.Composer,int,java.lang.String);
    void sourceInformationMarkerEnd(androidx.compose.runtime.Composer);
}

# Keep `Companion` object fields of serializable classes.
# This avoids serializer lookup through `getDeclaredClasses` as done for named companion objects.
-if @kotlinx.serialization.Serializable class **
-keepclassmembers class <1> {
    static <1>$Companion Companion;
}

# Keep `serializer()` on companion objects (both default and named) of serializable classes.
-if @kotlinx.serialization.Serializable class ** {
    static **$* *;
}
-keepclassmembers class <2>$<3> {
    kotlinx.serialization.KSerializer serializer(...);
}

# Keep `INSTANCE.serializer()` of serializable objects.
-if @kotlinx.serialization.Serializable class ** {
    public static ** INSTANCE;
}
-keepclassmembers class <1> {
    public static <1> INSTANCE;
    kotlinx.serialization.KSerializer serializer(...);
}

# @Serializable and @Polymorphic are used at runtime for polymorphic serialization.
-keepattributes RuntimeVisibleAnnotations,AnnotationDefault

-keepattributes *Annotation*, InnerClasses
-dontnote kotlinx.serialization.AnnotationsKt # core serialization annotations
-dontnote kotlinx.serialization.SerializationKt

 
# When kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonObjectSerializer occurs

-keepclassmembers class kotlinx.serialization.json.** {
    *** Companion;
}
-keepclasseswithmembers class kotlinx.serialization.json.** {
    kotlinx.serialization.KSerializer serializer(...);
}

# JSR 305 annotations are for embedding nullability information.
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**

# A resource is loaded with a relative path so the package of this class must be preserved.
-adaptresourcefilenames okhttp3/internal/publicsuffix/PublicSuffixDatabase.gz
 

# OkHttp platform used only on JVM and when Conscrypt and other security providers are available.
-dontwarn okhttp3.internal.platform.**
-dontwarn org.conscrypt.**
-dontwarn org.bouncycastle.**
-dontwarn org.openjsse.**
#################################### SLF4J #####################################
-dontwarn org.slf4j.**

# Prevent runtime crashes from use of class.java.getName()
-dontwarn javax.naming.**

# Ignore warnings
-ignorewarnings
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it because you have specified `-dontobfuscate` in the rules?

Comment: good point but no. Removing it doesn't change the issue I'm experiencing. I will remove it from the question to avoid confusion.